# Сортировка ArrayList содержащего объекты с вложенными данными

Tags: c#

Возможно ли в принципе отсортировать массив обьектов

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Phones_WPF
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>easddz
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }
        txtFileHandler firms = new txtFileHandler();
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            firms.ReadFromTXTWriteToArray(@"C:\Users\Odmen\Desktop\Firm_A.txt", @"C:\Users\Odmen\Desktop\Firm_B.txt");

            string output = firms.OutputArrayValues(firms.mobilePhones, firms.radioPhones, false);
            textBox1.Text = output;

            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Odmen\Desktop\New.txt", false, Encoding.Default))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(output);
            }


        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            firms.PutVariousValuesToOneArray(firms.mobilePhones, firms.radioPhones);
        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = firms.OutputArrayValues(firms.mobilePhones, firms.radioPhones, true);
        }

        private void TextBox_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //((TextBox)sender).SelectionLength = 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: как реализовать такую сортировку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы вам посоветовал вместо `ArrayList` возвращать `List<T>`, и потом использовать [OrderBy](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) в стиле:

```
var sorted = newfirms.PutVariousValuesToOneArray(firms.mobilePhones,
                                                 firms.radioPhones).OrderBy(p => p.Price);
```

Comment: а как в List<T> поместить элементы 2-х разных типов(MobilePhone, RadioPhone)

Comment: @Pavel Я думаю, что у `mobilePhones` и `radioPhones` все-таки есть общие свойства. Например цена. Вынесите ее в отдельный интерфейс и унаследуйте классы `mobilePhones` и `radioPhones` от него. После чего можно будет возвращать `List<IPhones>` (I говорит о том, что это интерфейс, а не айфон)).